# Matlab - distance matrix to table

Tags: matlab

How can I convert distance matrix generated by the following code (DM) to a table with a specific structure? I was think about a loop but I do not know how to construct it.

Code:

```
clc;
clear;

rng('default')  
X = rand(4);
DM = squareform(pdist(X))
```

Table structure:

```
Object1   Object2   Distance
1         2         0.7190
1         3         1.1237
1         4         0.8285  
2         1         0.7190
2         3         1.1790
2         4         0.5657
…         …         …
4         3         1.3360
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a logical index to remove the diagonal, and build the table from that:

```
ind = ~eye(size(DM));
[Object2, Object1] = find(ind);
Distance = DM(ind); % DM would need to be transposed first, but it is symmetric
result = table(Object1, Object2, Distance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using a for loop:

1. Build indices of first and second columns using `meshgrid`.
2. Convert indices and `DM` to column vectors.
3. Remove every 4'th element (object distance to itself).

---

Complete code sample:

```
clc;
clear;

rng('default')
X = rand(4);
DM = squareform(pdist(X));

d = length(X);

%Span combinations of rows / columns (indexes)
%C aplies Object1, R aplies Object2
[C, R] = meshgrid(1:d, 1:d);

%Reshape DM, C, R to a column vectors;
Dist = DM(:);
Obj1 = C(:);
Obj2 = R(:);

%Remove items with object distance to itself (i.e (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)).
Dist(1:d+1:end) = [];
Obj1(1:d+1:end) = [];
Obj2(1:d+1:end) = [];

%Concatenate columns to create a table:
T = [Obj1, Obj2, Dist];

%Table with named variables (if you really need it).
T_table = table(Obj1, Obj2, Dist);
```

---

Result:

```
T_table =

12×3 table

Obj1    Obj2     Dist  
____    ____    _______

 1       2        0.719
 1       3       1.1237
 1       4      0.82577
 2       1        0.719
 2       3        1.179
 2       4      0.56567
 3       1       1.1237
 3       2        1.179
 3       4        1.336
 4       1      0.82577
 4       2      0.56567
 4       3        1.336
```